# How do carpets make a room warmer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life

In winter , we put carpets on the ground , and this makes our room warmer . But I wondered about how it does make it warmer "scientifically"

Comment: I am inclined to think that it primarily provides extra insulation from the cold, but I don't know the thermodynamics of it.

Comment: The surface of a thermally poorly conducting carpet is much closer to the temperature of the air in the room than well conducting hard surfaces are, i.e. the radiation temperature and the air temperature in the room will be similar, which humans perceive as much more pleasant than unequal temperatures. There are also issues of convection currents which cause drafts, but those also depend a lot on the geometry and size of the room.

Comment: do they really make the room warmer or do we just perceive it to be warmer? has this been tested?  it seems to be insulation to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they really make the room warmer depends on the floor material underneath the carpet.

How warm the room actually is depends on the rate that heat is lost. If some heat is being lost through eg. a concrete floor with the cold ground underneath then anything with good insulation properties (ie. poor thermal conductivity) will reduce the rate of heat being lost and so make the room warmer. The carpet is the room "wearing" a coat.

If the floor isn't cold, eg a wooden floor with another warm room below. Then the carpet can still make the room feel warmer to your bare feet. The bare floor is likely to be colder than your body temperature, even if the room is warm, and so heat flows from your feet to the floor and you feel cold.

If there is a carpet then the rate of heat flow from your feet is much lower and so they don't feel cold.